# Getting error "For control variable already in use"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting error `For control variable already in use`. How to fix it? I got one macro for protecting and one for unprotecting (a button in a workbook, so that colleagues can use it too. Tried googling something, but I'm not that good at coding so here I am.

Here's the code:

Unprotecting:

```
Sub Unprotect_worksheets()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wPath As String, wQuan As Long, N As Long
    Dim fso As Object, folder As Object, subfolder As Object, wFile As Object
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        wPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With


    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set folder = fso.getfolder(wPath)
    
    wQuan = folder.Files.Count
    N = 1
    For Each wFile In folder.Files
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder : " & folder & ". File : " & N & " of : " & wQuan
        If Right(wFile, 4) Like "*xls*" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFile)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        
            For Each ws In wb.Sheet
                ws.Unprotect "123456"
            Next
            wb.Close True
        End If
        N = N + 1
    Next
    
    For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
        wQuan = subfolder.Files.Count
        N = 1
        For Each wFile In subfolder.Files
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder : " & subfolder & ". File : " & N & " of : " & wQuan
            If Right(wFile, 4) Like "*xls*" Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFile)
                For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                
                Next
                wb.Close True
            End If
            N = N + 1
        Next
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    
    Set fso = Nothing: Set folder = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Valmis!"
End Sub
```

Protecting:

```
Sub Protect_worksheets()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim wPath As String, wQuan As Long, N As Long
Dim fso As Object, folder As Object, subfolder As Object, wFile As Object

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    wPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With


Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set folder = fso.getfolder(wPath)

wQuan = folder.Files.Count
N = 1
For Each wFile In folder.Files
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder : " & folder & ". File : " & N & " of : " & wQuan
 If Right(wFile, 4) Like "*xls*" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFile)
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.Protect "12345", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
          , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
            AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
        ws.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions

    Next
    wb.Close True
    
    End If
    N = N + 1
Next

For Each subfolder In folder.subfolders
    wQuan = subfolder.Files.Count
    N = 1
    For Each wFile In subfolder.Files
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder : " & subfolder & ". File : " & N & " of : " & wQuan
        If Right(wFile, 4) Like "*xls*" Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFile)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            
            Next
            wb.Close True
        End If
        N = N + 1
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.StatusBar = False

Set fso = Nothing: Set folder = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing

MsgBox "Valmis!"
End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each ws In wb.Sheets` is repeated in the unprotecting sub.

Answer (score 0):

What's the meaning of this double loop:

```
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    
For Each ws In wb.Sheet
    ws.Unprotect "123456"
```

(It reads like a nested loop, re-using the same loop variable (which is plain wrong), but I believe it's a simple typo:

I believe that only the second part should be enough:

```
For Each ws In wb.Sheet
            ws.Unprotect "123456"
```